# Network Manager icon not visible in system tray

Tags: gnome, 14.04, network-manager, indicator

a few weeks ago I updated to Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS (clean install) and I noticed that the network manager icon is missing from the system tray. I have been going through a number of forums, but I couldn't find a solution that would fix this problem. My /etc/network/interfaces only contains the following:

> auto lo iface
>   lo inet loopback

Also, when calling nm-applet from the console it outputs:

> nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

Any ideas on how this could be fixed?

Comment: How can this be a copy if it was created 2 months BEFORE the other one?

Comment: That one has an answer sooo....okay...probably that one is a dupe of this! If you feel so, mark that question as a dupe of this. Let the mods decide what to do. No offense meant in marking this dupe BTW. Sorry! @Severin